# Inserting into a list alphabetically F# internal error

Tags: f#

I'm trying to write a recursive insert function that takes as parameters a string, a int, and a string*int list. However, when I make a call to the function, I keep getting an error

Here is the code:

```
type StringList = (string * int) list;;

let rec insert(name:string, value: int, s: StringList) =
  match s with
  | [] -> []
  | head :: (a,b) :: [] -> [(name,value)]
  | (a, b) :: tail ->
    if (a:string) = (name:string) then (name, value) :: (a, b) :: tail
    elif (a:string) < (name:string) then (a,b) :: insert(name,value,s)
    else (name, value) :: tail
```

When I call a function and insert a string that I know will be at the beginning of the list, I have no problem. For example:

```
> let s:StringList = [("a",3);("b",4);("c",5)];;
val s : StringList = [("a", 3); ("b", 4); ("c", 5)]

> insert("a",5,s);;
val it : (string * int) list = [("a", 5); ("a", 3); ("b", 4); ("c", 5)]
```

But when I try to insert an element not at the head of the list I get:

```
> insert("d",5,s);;


error FS0193: internal error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile - you have `match b with` but no `b`

Comment: What is the purpose of the `int` values? Do they matter for insertion order? The title says alphabetically, but nowhere in the question does it say or show the reason for the `int` value. It is just to add a bit of complexity to the problem to demonstrate another technique? If you are in a course it helps us to know the topic you are trying to learn so we can relate the code solution and give reasons that tie back to the course work. [Homework](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) questions are welcome here, so no reprimands for mentioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So aside from the minor error, you have:

```
elif (a:string) < (name:string) then (a,b) :: insert(name,value,s)
```

which causes infinite recursion which gives a stack overflow error.

you probably want

```
elif (a:string) < (name:string) then (a,b) :: insert(name,value,tail)
```